# Woocommerce, can't remove products from cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Few logged customers can't remove product from cart on cart page. After click "remove" button Woocommerce returns success message but product is still in basket. Is strange because only few customers have this problem.
What can be wrong?

Comment: The problem can be in the internet connection of client, clicking wrong button from their side and etc. :D . nobody can help you without problem part details, website url, debug infoo and etc. Or you waiting, that we'll start guess what can issue the problem?

Comment: It is no internet problem. I logged as customer which have a problem and I had the same bug.

Comment: i didn't expected, that it may be internet problem. I just noticed, that any guess will be a shot in the dark. You should to provide more details to get help

Comment: Hi Daniel, did you find a solution? This just happened to me.

Comment: Update: Woocommerce System Status indicates the cart page is missing shortcode. No clue how it vanished though.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to your web files, on your server?  If so, find your `.htaccess` file.  If this file is on your server, it would most likely be in the `httpdocs` Directory; the same place where you will find the `wp-admin`, `wp-content` and `wp-includes` folders.

Once you have found the `.htaccess` file:

1. Make a back up of the file.
2. Save the file to your Desktop.
3. Delete the file from your **server**.
4. Clear your Cache, on your browser.

Then add a few products to your Basket, followed by then deleting them.  See if this resolves your problem.

If this **does** resolve the issue, then it will be a method of elimination, as to ascertain which part of the `.htaccess` file is causing this caching glitch.  Simply upload the `.htaccess` file, including a little bit of the file, until the problem reappears.

If this **does not** resolve your problem, it would be a good idea as to ask those with the issue, what browser they are using, in case the issue is browser specific.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. I checked js console and php errors logs and nothing there.

Comment: I don't suppose you have any Caching Plugins, such as W3 Cache, installed on your WordPress site?  On that note, have you tried disabling all of your Plugins (minus 'WooCommerce') and then see if the problem is still present?

Comment: I don't use any cache plugin. I did like you said but still the same.

Comment: Hmmm ... Disable all Plugins (Minus 'WooCommerce').  Then install and activate WordPress' own Theme: https://en-gb.wordpress.org/themes/twentyseventeen/   Once done, perform your actions again.  If the problem still persists, it could be to do with your server.  If the problem has gone, then atleast we have identified that the problem lies within your Theme.